# Can't build contextify on ubuntu with node 8

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

This issue has been referenced in [bug reports](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/211), however this doesn't seem resolved. There are several packages that require `contextify` which seems to not build on Ubuntu and Node 8.x

On `npm install` various packages, I get the following error:

```
make: Entering directory '/src/node_modules/contextify/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
../src/contextify.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Local<v8::Context> ContextWrap::createV8Context(v8::Local<v8::Object>)':
../src/contextify.cc:131:68: warning: 'v8::Local<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance() const' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Local<Object> wrapper = Nan::New(constructor)->NewInstance();
                                                                    ^
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/v8.h:26:0,
                 from /root/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../src/contextify.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/v8.h:3851:52: note: declared here
   V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", Local<Object> NewInstance() const);
                                                    ^
/root/.node-gyp/8.10.0/include/node/v8config.h:318:3: note: in definition of macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
   declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
   ^
../src/contextify.cc:150:16: error: 'class v8::ObjectTemplate' has no member named 'SetAccessCheckCallbacks'
         otmpl->SetAccessCheckCallbacks(GlobalPropertyNamedAccessCheck,
```

Environment is:

```
Ubuntu Xenial 16.04
Node v8.10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error on node 9.11.1 on mac
the only way i was able to deal with it is following:

1. install NVM

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.9/install.sh | bash`

do not forget to add following to .bash_profile

```
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh  # This loads NVM
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

2. then `nvm install v6.9.5` and also if you need latest `nvm install node`
3. then `nvm use v6.9.5`, double check by node --version
4. `npm install` in your folder